# What is the nginx equivalent for this apache rule?

Tags: apache, nginx

I have the following apache rule. It basically needs to search for the "basicauth" token inside URLs and insert an Authorization header forward. I've been asked to provide an nginx equivalent of this - I don't use nginx. Can anyone please be so kind as to provide the nginx equivalent? I tried using online apache-nginx converters but one ignored the rule and the other produced what seems to be incorrect results.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)basicauth=([^&]+)
RewriteRule (.*) - [E=QS_TOKEN:%1]
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic %{QS_TOKEN}e" env=QS_TOKEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, inside the appropriate `location` block:

```
if ($query_string ~ "(?:^|&)basicauth=([^&]+)") {
    add_header Authorization "Basic $1";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the output of just another [htaccess to nginx converter](https://ext.plesk.com/packages/b33b9ba7-72c7-43a5-8454-f58236340563-htaccess-to-nginx). You might want to check this out.

```
if ($args ~ "(?:^|&)basicauth=([^&]+)"){
    set $rule_0 1$rule_0;
    set $bref_1 $1;
}
if ($rule_0 = "1"){
    setenv QS_TOKEN:$bref_1;
}
```